# how to avoid redundant association with composite relationship

Tags: uml, data-modeling, class-diagram

I have a composite relationship between two objects (A & B) (A is composed of many Bs). Now another class (C) has a one-to-many association relationship to class 'B'. I would like to be able to retrieve all instances of class (A) from class (C). 
How do I do this without creating redundant associations? Since 'C' has basically a list of 'Bs' I can't just iterate over all of them asking what's your 'A' and eventually returning a list of 'A' to 'C'.

I really hope someone out there understands this and doesn't find it completely confusing!

Thanks

Update:
Dataset has a list of defined variables. An activity can select a subset of variables from each dataset and give some attributes to them, hence an association class is used. Now if I want to be able to retrieve from an Activity instance the datasets it is registered with, how do I achieve this in UML and in object implementation?

Comment: a Java pseudocode or an ascii art class diagram or a class diagram picture would make your question much more readable (or just give A,B,C names from a real world metaphore). Do you ask about [how to model association navigability](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html) or how to implement the UML design in code so that you can easily jump from one pointer to another?

Comment: new profile, cant upload images yet! I hope my updated description makes more sense

Comment: A=Dataset, B=variable, C=Activity, Attribute binds B and C together and you want to know how to draw it in UML so that B->C->A is navigable? BTW: why you can't just iterate over the list of 'Bs'?

Comment: The question is if I need to define a method "retrieve datasets" from activity. What is the kind of relationship should I allow for this without being redundant? association by defining a collection of datasets inside activity or just a method to return datasets (usage dependency?) and in this latter case is iterating over variables is not considered a repetitive process each time a call is made to getDatasets?

Comment: in the implementation you can keep the results of querying C_Activity.getAllDatasets() cached in a private member variable of type List<A_Dataset> kept inside the C_Activity. This cache would be calculated by navigating over the original relationships automatically and invalidated when some of the relationships changes. I think it would be now better to talk about your code instead of the UML drawing. Can you edit your question and show us some (e.g. Java) code for the 4 A_Dataset, B_variable, C_Activity, Attribute classes?

Answer (score 0):

According to your task, it is IMPOSSIBLE to take all B's from all C's. Because there is no sentence that states that any B belong to some C.

On the contrary, as A have compositions of B (notice, A IS NOT composition, A HAS composition of B, for A can have heaps of other things, too), and any B MUST belong to some A object, you can easily get all B's from all A's. Only create the list of B as a set for not to have multiply values.

But even if the association B-A includes B->A connection, you cannot get all A's from B's. Because some A's can be EMPTY. You'll never reach them. from B's.

So, you cannot take all A from C's for TWO important reasons. And NO redundant association will help.

As for the question set after "Update",

- For getting All from variables, use

Dataset <---- Variable ---> Activity    // This variant is the easiest for adding associations.

- For getting connected datasets from an activity,

Dataset <--- Variable <----- Activity

But please, notice, it is not updated, it is DIFFERENT question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your diagram would look something like this :

[image]

If C has a reference to B, and B has a reference to A, then it should be no problem navigating to A from C. There is no need for any additional redundant relationships.

Comment: even if navigating from C to A means iterating over the subset of B's to find the associated A's? ..thanks

Comment: i guess so. unless you want to put in a relationship between C and A, but I would advise against it